# Prove $\sum_k \frac{a_k-z}{1-a_kz}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Problem statement: For $k \geq 1$ and $a_k = 1-\frac{1}{k^2}$, $|z| < r < 1$ in the complex plane. Prove $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |\frac{a_k-z}{1-a_kz} -1| $ converges.

If my computation is correct, we get $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |\frac{(a_k-1)(1+z)}{1-a_kz}| \leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty |\frac{(1/k^2)(1+r)}{(1-r)+(1/k^2)r}|$. Now root/ratio test does not seem to work...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sum_{k=1}^\infty |\frac{(1/k^2)(1+r)}{(1-r)+(1/k^2)r}|\leq \sum \frac {1+r} {(1-r)k^{2}} <\infty$

Comment: ..........nice........proof.......